# Solving A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

on following line:

```
df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

How I can solve this warning ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']]` creates a **new** dataframe which is a subset of `df3`. Since you are using `inplace=True` you are getting the aforementioned warning since it tries to modify the new dataframe inplace, to which you don't keep a reference around (and I suspect that if you'd print `df3` you will see that this line actually had no effect).

I'd do one of the following:

1. re-assign the newly created dataframe back to `df3` without using `inplace=True`:

   ```
   df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']] = \
   df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']].fillna(0)
   ```

Or the slightly preferable way (in my opinion at least):

2. Pass `fillna` the columns that you want to modify as a dictionary. The keys are the columns' names and the values are what `NaN` should be replaced with in each column:

   ```
   df3.fillna({'prod_tags_0': 0, 'prod_tags_1': 0,
               'prod_tags_2': 0, 'prod_tags_3': 0}, inplace=True)
   ```

   In this example you can use dictionary comprehension:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   df = pd.DataFrame({'prod_tags_0': [np.nan], 'prod_tags_1': [np.nan], 
                      'prod_tags_2': [np.nan]})

   print(df)
   >>     prod_tags_0  prod_tags_1  prod_tags_2
       0          NaN          NaN          NaN   

   df.fillna({'prod_tags_' + str(i): 0 for i in range(2)}, inplace=True)

   print(df)

   >>     prod_tags_0  prod_tags_1  prod_tags_2
       0          0.0          0.0          NaN
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the two answers here: both are correct. Indexing using the `df[["column"]]` syntax (note the double brackets) will indeed cause `inplace=True` to be ineffective because it is operating on a copy of the dataframe, but using `df.loc["column"]` - or for that matter `df["column"]` - with the inplace flag will succeed as expected, *despite throwing the warning*, which I believe is a bug.

Obviously DeepSpace's answer, particularly regarding the use of a dictionary as opposed to using fillna() on a slice of the DataFrame, is more elegant, but there is no reason one couldn't use `df["column"].fillna(0, inplace=True)` or `df.loc["column"].fillna(0, inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. re-assign the newly created `dataframe` back to `df3` without using `inplace=True`:

try this:

`df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']] = \`
`df3[['prod_tags_0', 'prod_tags_1', 'prod_tags_2', 'prod_tags_3']].fillna(0)`